# Listar las direcciones IP destino DIFERENTES que hay en un tcpdump

Tags: wireshark

No tengo claro si en este foro se tratan temas de redes, pero lo voy a intentar. Estamos realizando la migración de varios servidores y ahora estamos analizando el trafico de datos de nuestra empresa en busca de peticiones inútiles o maliciosas( peticiones a servicios que no existen o no existirán, a servicios que ya no usamos, o peticiones que no hayamos programado nosotros).

Entonces, teniendo un archivo con las peticiones extraídas por tcpdump, y analizándolo con Wireshark, me gustaría sacar un listado de las direcciones IP de destino **diferentes** a las que se hayan lanzado peticiones. Es decir, mostrar cada IP una sola vez, obviando las repeticiones (en el archivo puedo tener a lo mejor 1000 peticiones a una misma IP, quiero que solo salga una vez) para después investigar esas direcciones y gestionar las peticiones que queremos mantener y las que queremos eliminar.

Creo que la solución a esto puede ser mas sencilla de lo que pienso, pero soy bastante novato en temas de redes, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme. En caso de que este no sea el lugar apropiado para este tipo de consulta, agradeceré cualquier información sobre otros foros dedicados a las redes donde pueda volver a formularla.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Te sirve una solución en cualquier lenguaje de programación?

Comment: Diria que si, dado que me puede ayudar a darme ideas de como hacerlo. Si es en bash casi que mejor creo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bash es ... criptico ... Si la necesidad aprieta, uso Perl o Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Wireshark los paquetes capturados se pueden guardar en varios formatos, de los cuales elegi .csv, por ser el más fácil de procesar:

Para guardar en .csv, usar menú `File -> Export Packet Dissections -> as .CSV`

Obtuve este archivo `capture.csv`:

```
"No.","Time","Source","Destination","Protocol","Length","Info"
"1","0.000000000","RealtekS_53:44:58","AsustekC_82:2f:99","ARP","60","Who has 172.16.0.205? Tell 172.16.0.1"
"2","0.000024095","AsustekC_82:2f:99","RealtekS_53:44:58","ARP","42","172.16.0.205 is at e0:3f:49:82:2f:99"
"3","2.714359693","172.16.0.205","64.233.190.188","TCP","66","51364  >  5228 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=501 Len=0 TSval=2208270737 TSec
r=3483746177"
"4","2.750656283","64.233.190.188","172.16.0.205","TCP","66","[TCP ACKed unseen segment] 5228  >  51364 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2 Win=265 
Len=0 TSval=3483791218 TSecr=2207451935"
"5","2.842330521","172.16.0.205","198.252.206.25","TCP","66","37292  >  443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=501 Len=0 TSval=2177713120 TSecr
=2603821055"
```

El resto es simple: leer el archivo linea por linea y separar los campos. Usare Python, pero el método es traducible a otros lenguajes:

```
import sys

def extraer_destinos(nombre_archivo):
    """ Procesa un archivo Wireshark en formato csv

    @param nombre_archivo: Nombre del archivo .csv a procesar
    @return Lista ordenada de las ip de destino, sin repeticiones
    """

    # Protocolos que no interesa procesar.
    non_interested = ["ARP", "Protocol"]
    destinos = set()
    with open(nombre_archivo) as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            try:
                partes = line.split(",")
                source = partes[2][1:-1]
                destination = partes[3][1:-1]
                protocol = partes[4][1:-1]
                if protocol not in non_interested:
                    destinos.add(destination)
            except ValueError:
                # Ignoramos cualquier error generado por split
                pass

    lista = list(destinos)
    lista.sort()
    return lista

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Uso: extrae.py nombre_archivo")
    else:
        lista = extraer_destinos(sys.argv[1])
        for dest in lista:
            print(dest)
```

La función `extraer_destinos` retorna una lista ordenada, única, de IP de destino.

Guarda este programa con algún nombre y extensión .py, para que puedas ejecutarlo desde línea de comando (por ejemplo, extrae.py)

Este programa se puede ejecutar desde la línea de comandos. Necesitas tener un interprete de Python, lo cual esta disponible sin costo para cualquier plataforma:

Probemos:

```
candid@gear:~/PycharmProjects/pandas$ python extrae.py capture.csv
151.101.193.164
172.16.0.1
172.16.0.205
172.217.192.100
172.217.192.121
172.217.192.92
172.217.192.94
198.252.206.25
40.102.34.210
64.233.186.100
64.233.186.138
64.233.190.188
64.233.190.94
77.88.21.125
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Lo probaré ahora.

Comment: Confirmado! funciona, muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, estoy ampliando las funciones del programa para que pueda hacer otras cosas. Que parte del codigo es la que evita que se almacenen Ip's ya almacenadas?

Comment: @ROGERMOCHOLISEGURA. Las IP se almacenan en un **set**. El set automaticamente descarta los duplicados. No es necesario ninguna acciòn explicita.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias. Para acabar de entender el codigo, que significan los `[1:-1]`?

Comment: @ROGERMOCHOLISEGURA. Todo menos el primer y último caracter del string. O sea, eliminar las cremillas, dejando sólo la IP. Propiamente hablando, es un *slice*, un trozo de un string o lista entre determinados indices. Aprende sobre ellos, que son una parte importante en Python.

Comment: Estoy en ello! muchas gracias, encantado de ser tu padawan brevemente